# How to detect emotions with Azure API?

Tags: python, azure, face-detection

I'd like to create a simple Python app recognizing face emotions from given URL via Azure Face/Emotions API.
I'm following this documentation:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/face/quickstarts/python-sdk#authenticate-the-client
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-cognitiveservices-vision-face/azure.cognitiveservices.vision.face.models.emotion?view=azure-python

So, far, I did the face recognition part, but I'm kinda stuck how to call the Emotion model and display results.

```
import urllib.request  
from azure.cognitiveservices.vision.face import FaceClient
from azure.cognitiveservices.vision.face.models import Emotion
from msrest.authentication import CognitiveServicesCredentials

# Image
URL = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/55/Dalailama1_20121014_4639.jpg"

# API
KEY = "xxx"
ENDPOINT = "https://happyai.cognitiveservices.azure.com/"

# Now there is a trained endpoint that can be used to make a prediction
predictor = FaceClient(ENDPOINT, CognitiveServicesCredentials(KEY))

detected_faces = predictor.face.detect_with_url(url=URL)
if not detected_faces:
    raise Exception('No face detected from image {}'.format(URL))

# Display the detected face ID in the first single-face image.
# Face IDs are used for comparison to faces (their IDs) detected in other images.
print('Detected face ID from', URL, ':')
for face in detected_faces: print (face.face_id)
print()

# Save this ID for use in Find Similar
first_image_face_ID = detected_faces[0].face_id

# Call Emotion model

# Display the results.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to do the emotion detection,

```
def det_emotion(self, frame, count):

        image_path = self.path_folder + "/img/frame%d.jpg" % count
        image_data = open(image_path, "rb")

        params = {
            'returnFaceId': 'true',
            'returnFaceLandmarks': 'false',
            'returnRecognitionModel':'false',
        }

        response = requests.post(self.face_api_url, params=params,data=image_data)
        response.raise_for_status()
        faces = response.json()
        frame = self.add_square(frame, faces)

        return frame
```

Comment: I think that won't work, because my API works differently. I have an endpoint and key, not whole api url.

Comment: what do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

in order to get the emotion in return, you need to specifically define the 'emotion' attribute you want to return in the "return_face_attributes" of the 'detect_with_url' function. Please refer to the following code:

```
face_attributes = ['emotion']
detected_faces = predictor.face.detect_with_url(url=URL, return_face_attributes=face_attributes)
```

Then when you loop through all the detected faces, you can reach the Emotion object of each face by calling:

```
for face in detected_faces:
    emotionObject = face.face_attributes.emotion
```

The emotionObject contains 8 different emotions: 'anger', 'contempt', 'disgust', 'fear', 'happiness', 'neutral', 'sadness', 'surprise'.
Since the emotionObject is not an iterable object, and I don't know how to get just the emotion with the highest confident, so I wrote a sub function to convert it into a dictionary type and add it into the face iteration loop:

```
def get_emotion(emoObject):
    emoDict = dict()
    emoDict['anger'] = emoObject.anger
    emoDict['contempt'] = emoObject.contempt
    emoDict['disgust'] = emoObject.disgust
    emoDict['fear'] = emoObject.fear
    emoDict['happiness'] = emoObject.happiness
    emoDict['neutral'] = emoObject.neutral
    emoDict['sadness'] = emoObject.sadness
    emoDict['surprise'] = emoObject.surprise
    emo_name = max(emoDict, key=emoDict.get)
    emo_level = emoDict[emo_name]
    return emo_name, emo_level

for face in detected_emotional_faces:
    emotion, confidence = get_emotion(face.face_attributes.emotion)
    print("{} emotion with confidence level {}".format(emotion, confidence))
```